# Move navigation bar next to the image in the header

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS and I have a problem with moving the navigation bar next to the image in the header. I have been trying a lot with margin, floats etc., but it does not seem to work. Could anybody give me an advice. Thanks :)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="unilogo.png" width="100">
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Modules</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Timetable</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Career Opportnuities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 9%;
}

.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 15%;
    margin-top: 0%
}

.logo{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 1%
}

.logo img{
    width: 22%;
    height: 1%;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

.nav{
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-top: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `display:inline-block;` to both classes .logo and .nav

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/459qmhrw/

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply a width. You have already floated them, but if they are 100% in width then they will not sit side by side:

```
.logo{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 1%
    max-width: 20%;
}

.nav{
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    margin-top: 0%;
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply widths to the .nav and .logo classes, equaling 100%. If they still don't line up right, adjust the widths to equal 95%, then 90%, etc.

Also, you might want to take the "width="100"" attribute out of the  tag in your HTML. You've specified a percentage for the image in your CSS, which is where it should be.